# Quadtree based polygon indexing? (Python/Java)

Tags: python, polygon, geojson, java, quadtree

I was wondering how to best represent the inside of any given polygon (GeoJSON coordinates) with some sort of indexing, like a grid or quadtree? See image below for an approximation of what I have in mind.

[image]

Is there any library in Python or Java that can help me with this?

Comment: If you have a single polygon, how would you define the varied tile resolution that are inside? tile angle?

Comment: What's the use case?  How about rtree?  http://toblerity.org/rtree/

Comment: How is this image created from the QuadTree? I need to do something similar

Answer (score 0):

Java JTS has a Quadtree implementation built in.

https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/index/quadtree/Quadtree.html